# Q: mgcv::gam() with constraints on the coefficents

Tags: r, constraints, gam, mgcv

I'm fitting a logit GAM model and need to impose an inequality constraint on betas in the smooth terms. I've tried `mgcv::pcls()`, but it seems I can't specify the independent inequalities for the different spline coefficients.  What's the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer myself, posting it just in case someone will look for it. The `mono.con` function in `mgcv` generates constraint matrices Ain and bin. For several splines, Ain matrices should be just put together into a single block-diagonal matrix.

Comment: Can you please share your code? It sounds like you want to impose constraints on , b1 and b2 here: `y = a + b1 * s(x1, ... ) + b2 * s(x2, ...)` - but the documentation doesn't seem to have an example for this. Thanks!